# Conversion Failed When Converting the Varchar value 'ListViewItem:{2}' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

Following query is not inserting value in database.

Code:

```
 try
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < listViewSubject.Items.Count; i+=2)
      {
           string query = "INSERT INTO Std_Subjects (subject_id, std_reg_id) VALUES ('" + listViewSubject.Items[i] + "', '" + this.reg_id + "')";
           dal.InsertUpdateDelete(query);
      }
      conn.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. This is more type safe, allows for query plans to be reused and prevents SQL Injection. Getting back to your question, when you debug, what value of `listViewSubject.Items[i]` causes it to fail?

Comment: What is the type of your `subject_id` and `std_reg_id` columns? Smells like they are not character.

Comment: It returns an array. Example Like this:- {2} OR {1}.

Comment: @user3451850 If the column types are `int`, why you want to insert them as `'2','1'` ? Single quotes for character types, not integer types. Don't use them in your `VALUES` part.

Comment: You mean I should write like this:-   INSERT INTO Std_Subjects (subject_id, std_reg_id) VALUES (" + listViewSubject.Items[i] + ", " + this.reg_id + ")"?

Comment: @user3451850 Basically, yes. **But** please use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I understand the issue is error with converting to int.You have to convert subject ID to int before inserting.

```
    Try
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < listViewSubject.Items.Count; i+=2)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Std_Subjects (subject_id, std_reg_id) VALUES (" + Int.Parse(listViewSubject.Items[i].Text) + ", " + this.reg_id + ")";
            dal.InsertUpdateDelete(query);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Hope this.reg_id is also int. If not convert it as I converted the subject id. Please note that I have removed single quote from

> '" + listViewSubject.Items[i] + "', '" + this.reg_id + "'

This is the method using parameterized query:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < listViewSubject.Items.Count; i+=2)
        {

         string query = "INSERT INTO Std_Subjects (subject_id, std_reg_id) VALUES (@subjectID,@StdRegId)";
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectID",Int.Parse(listViewSubject.Items[i].Text));
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StdRegId", this.reg_id);
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation. That would be more informative for OP.

Comment: My Friend It showing this error when I used your code:- Error:-
 The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You forget to add .Text to listViewSubject.Items[i]. Now I've corrected the answer..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `listViewSubject.Items[i]` returns a value 'ListViewItem:{2}' rather than an integer. Depending on what kind of object your item collection returns you may want to debug it. Probably `listViewSubject.Items[i].Value` might work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what your data access layer does behind the scenes, but using the basic SqlCommand I would be inclined to do your insert as follows:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Std_Subjects (subject_id, std_reg_id) VALUES (@SubjectID, @RegID)";
for (int i = 0; i < listViewSubject.Items.Count; i+=2)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add("@RegID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.reg_id;
        command.Parameters.Add(SubjectID, SqlDbType.Int).Value = listViewSubject[i].Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```